# How working of Javascript Single thread & NodeJS single thread differs in terms of flow execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in the middle of building data modeling in MongoDB which will work with Nodejs. I am keen to understand the basic level working of how threads handle flow of execution in Javascript. Basically i want to understand if their is any difference in terms of execution of threads of Javascript & Nodejs. The javascript is single threaded and the Nodejs built upon v8 javascript is also single threaded! What could be the breakthrough difference in terms of execution  between these two.

Comment: Javascript is a language, Node is an engine that runs this language.

Comment: @JeremyThille To be pedantic Node is an environment, V8 is the JS engine

Comment: I was trying to simplify things :)

Comment: I don't think any of this should matter. The main point is that your script is running in one thread, but it does allow external calls which can be executed in an asynchronous fashion and call a callback when they are done. If you do want to look under the hood, Node, the Chrome browser, and even MongoDB are all using [Google's V8 JavaScript engine,](https://developers.google.com/v8/) and it will likely run very similar in each of them.

Answer (score 1):

The terminology in your question is a bit messed up and thus it appears your question is a bit misdirected.  Trying to compare "Javascript" to node.js does not really make sense.  node.js runs Javascript code just fine.  You don't really compare the two.  I'm going to assume that what you meant to compare is "Javascript in the Chrome browser" vs. "Javascript in node.js".

The main thread of Javascript in both Chrome (or any other browser) and node.js is single threaded.  They behave the same in that regard and, in fact, node.js and Chrome use the exact same V8 Javascript execution engine.  All coordination with the outside world or with other native code is via the event queue.

Modern browsers do have webWorkers which allow additional threads of Javascript, but those threads are very restricted in what they can do (for example, they cannot access the DOM) and in how they can communicate with the main Javascript thread (all communication is via messaging - direct function calls or shared variables are not allowed).  webWorkers are almost as isolated as separate processes would be in node.js.

Both Chrome and node.js have native code libraries that use native threads to implement their work, but when they interface with the user's Javascript code, they all go through the event queue and that's how they connect with the single threaded Javascript code.